# Why does my code fail to connect to a Selenium Remote Webdriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc

I m trying to do automation testing using "Selenium Remote Webdriver" but getting an exception when try to connect with remote server.

**The exception is:**

```
Unexpected error. System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:4444
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute) in c:\Projects\WebDriver\trunk\dotnet\src\WebDriver\Remote\HttpCommandExecutor.cs:line 109
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters) in c:\Projects\WebDriver\trunk\dotnet\src\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver.cs:line 836
```

**The code I have written is:**

```
            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.Firefox();
            capabilities.Platform = new Platform(PlatformType.Vista);
            capabilities.SetCapability("api_key", "REPLACE_API_KEY");
            capabilities.SetCapability("api_secret", "REPLACE_API_SECRET");  


            var remoteAddress = new Uri("http://122.176.112.91:4444/wd/hub");

           // ... but only if it supports javascript
            capabilities.IsJavaScriptEnabled = true;


            // Get a handle to the driver. This will throw an exception
            // if a matching driver cannot be located
            IWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(remoteAddress, capabilities);
            driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30));


            // Query the driver to find out more information
            ICapabilities actualCapabilities = ((RemoteWebDriver)driver).Capabilities;
```

Please help me to sort out this prolem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well is there a Selenium instance listening at `http://122.176.112.91:4444/wd/hub`?

Comment: firewall issue perhaps?

Comment: try to change the port number. hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace indicates the local machine is actively refusing any connections.  Double-check that Firefox is permitted on all ports by the firewalls.

Unfortunately, I've encountered this problem even when the firewall is open:
[C# + VisualStudio + Multiple WebDriver instances = SocketExceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27029988/c-sharp-visualstudio-multiple-webdriver-instances-socketexceptions)